# How we can rotate select box using asp.net select control?

Tags: asp.net, select, drop-down-menu

I am trying rotate select option vertically. like want to text rotate as per given pic but my problem is unable to work position as well as rotation on option element.
My code is-

```
  <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="260px" style="position: relative;">
            <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <select id="ddlBooks" runat="server" class="divMenu"   onchange="
        if(this.selectedIndex !=0) 
            document.getElementById('pValue').innerHTML = 'You choose: ' + this.value; 
        else 
            document.getElementById('pValue').innerHTML = '';">
</select>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                     <asp:TableCell>
                          <%--SHOW SELECT VALUE.--%>
<p id="pValue"></p>

                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
        </asp:Panel>
```

css is

```
 <style>
        .st {
            
    transform: rotate(90deg);
        }  
              .asp {
            transform: rotate( 270deg );
    writing-mode: tb-rl;
    padding: 0px 6px;
}
        select,#ddlBooks  *{
        webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    width: 69vh;
    height: 50px;
    top: 269px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -175px;
         }
        #ddlBooks option {
            position:absolute;
             webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    width: 69vh;
    height: 50px;
    top: 269px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -175px;
        }
        #ddlBooks option:nth-child(2n+1) {
            background:red
        }
    </style>
```

[my option pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sZSa.png)

wanted option like as following e.g;
[wanted style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nDqm.png)

right now i have

Comment: Hi, please provide a minimum working solution/code that potential users answering your question could use to reproduce your issue. It seems also that you missed the current results picture (the last sentence cut "right now I have" and nothing follows). You will increase your chance to get help.

Comment: sorry for that, I am mention above now